# Wingpanel takes up 100% of the CPU

Tags: wingpanel, bugs, horus

I'm not sure if I'm the only one with this problem, but since a few days Wingpanel has started to occupy the CPU to 100%.

[image: HTop]

That definitely can't be intentional, or am I wrong?